# Bind a device reboot to keyboard or mouse

Tags: windows, drivers

I have an issue with my laptop, every once in a while, with no apparent cause, the screen goes black and I can't do anything. I have to force-shut down with power button.

It happens once or twice a week or so. 
Once every 3 or 4 times, it just so happens that windows recovers on its own and displays a "Intel HD Graphic 530 Card driver has stopped working and has been restored..".

Guided by that error message, I managed to plug in a second monitor when this happens and from there go into the devices manager, disable the Intel HD graphics and then re-enable it. Problem fixed.

**Now I no longer have the 2nd monitor, so how can I go about rebooting the device (<-- THE INTEL HD CARD, from device manager, NOT THE LAPTOP) when I can't see anything on the screen? Keybind maybe?**

**NOTE:**

The driver is up to date, nothing can be done about that..

I have a secondary GPU NVIDIA but I can't use that for everything for external reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You dont really need a keybinding.  Just type:

> <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>shutdown /r /f /t 0<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that the parameter after /t is a zero

This invokes the Run dialog box, where you can type the reboot command, forcing immediate reboot

Comment: Yeah but I might not want a reboot, in fact, I dont: I need to reboot a device (Intel HD Graphics), not windows.

Comment: @Athamas you said in your post you want to reboot...

Comment: Rebooting the device, device meaning the Intel HD Graphic card, from Device Manager.